# Panel truncate error: tuple object has no attribute 'year'

Tags: python, pandas

I am running code on two separate machines, it works on one machine and not on the other. I have a Pandas panel object x and I am using x.truncate('2002-01-01'). It works on one machine and not the other.

The error thrown is DateParseError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'year'.

I have some inkling there is something wrong with the dateUtil package upgrade but didn't know if there's a better fix than backwardating the install.

Comment: Are the two machines running different versions of Python?

Comment: No, they are both Python 2.7 - one is a Linux Debian digitalOcean machine, the other is a macbook pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dateutil 2.2 there was an internal API change. Pandas 0.12 shows this bug as it relies on this API.

Pandas >= 0.13 works around, or you can downgrade to dateutil 2.1